# Selecting the current month folder in source using Azure data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want my azure pipeline to always select the current month folder in my source copy activity container and don't want to manually change the folder to the new month every month for example:

[image]

You can see the folder points to this month, but when we enter Jan 2021 the folder must automatically point to Jan 2021 and all the contents in that new month folder.

Is there a way to achieve this using dynamic content?

I have tried this string but it does not seem to work:

@concat(pipeline().parameters.ExecutionFolder,  '/',formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyy'),  '/',formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'MM')

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a test and it works well. I'm using Azure data lake gen2 as file storage.
This is my file structure:
[image]

1. I've created a source dataset to link the container.
   [image]
2. Declare a parameter with the default value `stderr`.
   [image]
3. At the source setting. I select `Wildcard file path` option and enter `@concat(pipeline().parameters.ExecutionFolder, '/',formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyy'), '/',formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'MM'))`. The end of the path is a wildcard `*`.
   [image]
4. After I run debug, all files in this path have been copied.
   [image]

Comment: Thank you very much Joseph, it now works perfectly.

Comment: Appreciate your help, have a great festive season.

Comment: @Rayno Matthee You are welcome.  If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you!

Comment: @Rayno Matthee  Have a great festive season!